# Python 3 - Functions - Exception Handling

Tags: python-3.x, function, exception

The below piece of code calculates the user's [Body Mass Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index). There is a function that performs the calculation after the user has provided his or her body weight (kg) and height (m). A message with the user's BMI value is also printed.

The code includes also some Exception Handling in order errors to be avoided. For example, if a string is provided instead of a number or if an extreme value is provided (e.g. a height greater than 2.40m) then a special message is printed (e.g. "Please enter your height correctly!).

```
def find_bmi(weight,height):
    my_bmi=weight/height**2
    return my_bmi

try:
    weight=float(input("What is your weight (kg)?"))
    if weight < 200:
        height=float(input("What is your height (m)?"))
        try:
            if height < 2.40:
                print("Your BMI is: "+str(round(find_bmi(weight,height),2))+"!!!")        
            else:
                print("Please enter your height correctly!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number please!")
    else:
        print("Please enter your weight correctly")
except ValueError:
    print("Enter a number please!")
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to write this? Is there something that could have been written in a better way? Bear in mind that I have recently started learning Python!

Comment: Just try to split your return logic in other func. In this case if call your func .like.... Find_bmi(100,1.5) but it will use user input only so there is no point to run this func like that. And if I call it like...find_bmi() ...it will give you ,your calculated bmi and then error for required parameters during function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_bmi(weight, height):
    return weight/(height**2)

def prompt():
    try:
        weight, height = [float(a) for a in input("Enter space separated 
        weight(kg) and height(m), weight height\n").split()]
        return weight, height
    except ValueError:
        raise Exception("Enter a number please!")

def range_error(weight, height):
    raise Exception("height out of range") if height >= 2.40 else null
    raise Exception("weight out of range") if weight >= 200 else null

weight, height = prompt()
range_error(weight,height) if (height >=2.40 or weight >=200) else print("Your BMI is: "+str(round(find_bmi(weight,height),2))+"!!!")
```

Comment: what's the issue ? I think you have copied code from here using CTRL + C. Don't do that

Comment: This is not helpful

Comment: Can you please speicify what is causing the issue?